# C++ - include unistd.h: why not cunistd?

Tags: c++, c

It's said that when including C header files in C++, the ".h" suffix should be removed and then add "c" at the beginning. For example, `#include <cstdio>`  instead of `#include <stdio.h>`. But when I use `sleep()` in my code, `#include <cunistd>` does not work, but `#include <unistd.h>` works. Why not `<cunistd>`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct for most (all?) standard C headers, but `unistd.h` is not part of standard C so standard C++ in turn doesn't include it with the other `c...` headers.

Answer (score 40):

Because `unistd.h` never was part of the C language. It is part of the Operating System.

Answer (score 22):

`<unistd.h>` , stands for unix standard header ,the name says it all.

Comment: ...so that's what the name says!

Comment: `unistd` could just as well stand for "universal standard header" (I realize that sounds a bit ridiculous). The point is, they should've named it `unixstd.h` -- instant clarity by adding just _one_ character.

Answer (score 6):

unistd.h is not part of standard C.
Standard C++ lib doesn't include it with the other c headers.