# making sure program is in a terminal

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I was trying to add colors to some strings that have to be displayed in a terminal using ansi escape code. So far I haven't grasped the whole ascii escapes code thing, just trying out by copy pasting some escape codes. Then saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760577/2648679) which asked to verify that program should check that its being executed in a terminal or else continue without polluting strings with escape codes?

Answer explains to use a *nix based function `isatty()` which I found out resides in `unistd.h` which in turn wasn't promoted to `cunistd` by cpp standard based on my understanding that it wasn't in c's standard at first place.I tried to search [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157038) again but wasn't able to understand well. Now I have two questions regarding this :

- In what environment(right word?) can a program - using ascii escape codes, be executed that it requires an initial check? since I'm bulding for cli only.
- What would be a proper solution according to ISO cpp standards for handling this issue? using `unistd.h`? would this use confine to modern cpp practices?

Also is there anything I should read/understand before dealing with ansi/colors related thing?

Comment: `unistd.h` is a POSIX header, which is entirely orthogonal to the C and C++ standards. I don't think either of those standards has any notion of a terminal, so you have little choice but to depend on system APIs for system-specific functionality.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331566/c-include-unistd-h-why-not-cunistd .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a POSIX system (like Linux or OSX) the [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function is indeed the correct function to determine if you're outputting to a terminal or not.

Use it as this

```
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
{
    // Output using VT100 control codes
}
else
{
    // Output is not a TTY, could be a pipe or redirected to a file
    // Use normal output without control codes
}
```

Comment: pipes & redirects == bash's `|` and `>` ?  and what is VT100? my knowledge is limited to tty,pty,shells and gui-terminals :(

Comment: You should use the termcap library to get escape sequences, rather than hard-coding the sequences for a particular terminal. But all modern terminal emulators use sequences based on VT100 terminal from the 70's.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal [Wikipedia is your friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) :)

Comment: @Barmar I am currently reading about terminfo, and I guess I should be using this over termcap, right? Users report terminfo part working in OSX too.